# Как "склеить" результат запроса в строку через разделитель?

Tags: sql-server

Имеется следующая схема БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как на стороне сервера *склеить* исполнителей заявки для приведенной схемы?

---

Что пытался сделать сам:

```
SELECT
  r.Id AS RequestId,
  r.OpeningDate,
  rh.Note
FROM Requests r
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    *
  FROM RequestHistories rh
  WHERE rh.Id IN (SELECT MAX(_rh.Id) AS Id FROM RequestHistories _rh GROUP BY _rh.RequestId)) rh
  ON r.Id = rh.RequestId
INNER JOIN RequestHistoryPerformers rhp
  ON rh.Id = rhp.RequestHistoryId
WHERE r.ClosingDate IS NULL
```

этим запросом я начинаю собирать необходимое мне *представление*, но не могу понять как мне в результирующий запрос добавить `LastName` из таблицы Performers через разделитель, т.е. получить что то типа *Иванов, Петров*

Пытался делать при помощи [`for xml path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/5610621):

```
Select
  r.Id as RequestId
  , r.OpeningDate
  , (select _p.LastName + ',' from performers _p where _p.Id=rhp.PerformerId for xml path('')) as Performers
```

но к сожалению не смог добиться необходимого результата

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7aa8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно `RequestHistoryPerformers` внести в подзапрос, где происходит склейка строк.

Как-то так:

```
SELECT
    r.Id AS RequestId,
    r.OpeningDate,
    rh.Note,
    Performers = stuff((
        select ', ' + _p.LastName
        from performers _p
            join RequestHistoryPerformers rhp ON _p.Id = rhp.PerformerId
        where rhp.RequestHistoryId = rh.Id
        order by _p.LastName
        for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM Requests r
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 rh.*
        FROM RequestHistories rh
        WHERE rh.RequestId = r.Id
        ORDER BY rh.Id DESC
    ) rh
WHERE r.ClosingDate IS NULL
```

Можно подзапрос вынести в `OUTER APPLY`, как посоветовали в соседнем ответе.

Также, из `RequestHistories` вы берёте последнюю запись для данного `RequestId`. Я бы это чуть-чуть по другому сделал.

Comment: Перекрестный запрос мне понятен, а в чем разница способов получения как у Вас и у меня? а вот магия в  `stuff` мне совсем непонятна. сейчас попробую покурить инет

Comment: @Bald, _"способов получения"_ - вы имеете ввиду склейку ? Или обращение к `RequestHistories`?

Comment: я имел ввиду получение последней записи для заявки из истории, т.е. текущее состояние у Вас это сделано через перекрестный запрос...

Comment: @Bald, в вашем варианте `RequestHistories` будет в плане запроса участвовать дважды (обращение к таблице и ещё одно, где группировка). В моём варианте будет одно обращение, т.е. план чуть поэффективнее должен быть.

Comment: @Bald, да, и у меня там ошибочка затесалась - вместо `WHERE rh.RequestId = rh.Id` должно быть `WHERE rh.RequestId = r.Id` (исправил).

Comment: Эту ошибку я видел, буду разбираться с функцией `stuff`, спасибо за разъяснение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40311/discussion-between-bald-and-i-one).

Answer (score 1):

Обычно через `for xml path` и делается:
Если по примеру на SQLFiddle - то так:

```
select rhp.RequestHistoryId, 
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [LastName] 
    FROM performers _p 
    join RequestHistoryPerformers r on r.PerformerId=_p.Id
    where r.RequestHistoryId=rhp.RequestHistoryId
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') PerformersNames
 from RequestHistoryPerformers rhp
group by rhp.RequestHistoryId
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server