# Как преобразовать результат SQL запроса из столбцов в одну строку из FastReport

Tags: sql, fastreport, sql-server-2005

Необходимо преобразовать столбцы возвращаемые SQL-запросом в одну строку из FastReport 4 (SQL Server 2005)

Например:

```
value  temp
10.55  16.1 
88.77  21.0
```

преобразовать в

```
value: 10.55, temp: 16.1, value: 88.77, temp: 21.0
```

Везде даются примеры с XML и т.п., но они не работает из FastReport.

Comment: не работает из FR,  в смысле что он не дает такой запрос куда нить в тело датасета вписать? или что?

Comment: В хелпер по FastReport 4 есть пример "печать ценников", где рассказывается про постолбцовую печать многоколончатого отчета

Comment: А не проще откорректировать запрос и сразу получать нужную форму данных? У SQL server проблем с XML не будет...

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527340/179270), там есть пример, как на стороне сервера собрать необходимую вам строку.